# monacaでのiphone横画面固定の方法

Tags: ios, monaca

monacaのIDEを使って簡単なゲームを作っています.
横画面固定の設定をしたいのですが,公式のドキュメントにあった通りMonaca-AppInfo.plistの中にある,UISupportedInterfaceOrientationsの箇所を編集して,

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
  <array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
  </array>
```

のようにしました.
認識としては縦画面の行を消す(→不許可)ことで横画面にしか対応していない設定にしたという解釈なのですが,プレビューや実機デバッグをしてみても反映されません.
これは設定に失敗しているのでしょうか.
それとも実際にiOSアプリとしてビルドしないと確認できないものですか?

Answer (score 1):

その設定はビルドするまで反映されません。
ビルドする際にその設定が読み込まれます。
ですので、デバッガーやプレビューへ即時に反映されるものではありません。

Info.plistはビルド設定なのです。